# Correction of Shostakovich's quote "давайте выпем за то, чтобы лучше не былa (бы)" in documentary "Shostakovich against Stalin"

Tags: перевод

In [*Shostakovich against Stalin*](http://youtu.be/irYM2VcBv4A?t=12m51s) documentary it's explained how Shostakovich once reacted to Stalin's oppinion ("life is now better", "let's make life better") by proposing a toast and sarcastically saying, according to the subtitules there:

> *Let's drink to life not getting any better*.

I think I hear

> "давайте выпем за то, чтобы лучше не былa (бы)"  (Д.Ш.)

Now *бы* is in parenthesis, since I'm totally unsure if that's the word pronounced after былa (or maybe *было*). First question would be to confirm this. The second question is, if this a better translation?

> "Let's drink to life, for it not be that good."

I mean, given the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He says *давайте выпьем за то, чтобы лучше не было бы*, so subtitles translation is correct. Notice the accent: не́ было / не была́.